# Automated Ripping Machine (ARM) - ripping to flac, not ripping to mp3

Tags: cd, mp3, flac, abcde

So I configured ARM and it was working correctly for flac files. However when I set it up for mp3 (I am doing it for someone else end they prefer mp3) it is not working.

As for the logs:

```
[2019-11-17 00:01:17] INFO ARM: Starting ARM processing at 2019-11-17    00:01:17.3539
[2019-11-17 00:01:17] INFO ARM: ARM version: 2.0.1-stable
[2019-11-17 00:01:17] INFO ARM: Python version: 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) [GCC 8.3.0]
[2019-11-17 00:01:17] INFO ARM: Looking for log files older than 1 days old.
[2019-11-17 00:01:17] INFO ARM: Starting Disc identification
[2019-11-17 00:01:17] INFO ARM: Mounting disc to: /mnt/dev/sr1
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: **** Logging ARM variables ****
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: devpath: /dev/sr1
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: mountpoint: /mnt/dev/sr1
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: videotitle: 
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: videoyear: 
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: videotype: 
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: hasnicetitle: False
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: label: LimpBizkitECD
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: disctype: music
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: **** End of ARM variables ****
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: **** Logging config parameters ****
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: skip_transcode: False
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: mainfeature: True
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: minlength: 600
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: maxlength: 99999
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: videotype: auto
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: ripmethod: backup
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: mkv_args: 
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: delrawfile: True
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: hb_preset_dvd: High Profile
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: hb_preset_bd: High Profile
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: hb_args_dvd: --subtitle scan -F
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: hb_args_bd: --subtitle scan -F --subtitle-burned --audio-lang-list eng --all-audio
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: logfile: /home/arm/logs/LimpBizkitECD.log
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: armpath: /home/arm/Desktop
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: rawpath: /home/arm/media/raw/
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: media_dir: /home/arm/media/movies/
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: extras_sub: extras
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: emby_refresh: False
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: emby_server: 
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: emby_port: 8096
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: notify_rip: True
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: notify_transcode True
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: **** End of config parameters ****
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: Disc identified as music
[ERROR] abcde: mp3gain is not in your path.
[INFO] Define the full path to the executable if it exists on your system.
[INFO] Hint: sudo apt-get install 
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] ERROR ARM: Call to abcde failed with code: 1(b'')
[2019-11-17 00:01:21] INFO ARM: Music rip failed.  See previous errors.  Exiting.
```

it seems there is wrong path to an mp3 encoder, however when i look at abcde.conf file the path seems alright to me.

```
# -----------------$HOME/.abcde.conf----------------- #
# 
# A sample configuration file to convert music cds to 
#       FLAC using abcde version 2.7.2
# 
#       http://andrews-corner.org/abcde.html
# -------------------------------------------------- #
#
# This script was copied from the above site with the following modification:
#
# Set to non-interactive
# CDDMETHOD=cddb since it's more reliable (for my CDs)
# Enabled getalbumart
# Change output format from artist-album to artist/album



INTERACTIVE=n

# Encode tracks immediately after reading. Saves disk space, gives
# better reading of 'scratchy' disks and better troubleshooting of
# encoding process but slows the operation of abcde quite a bit:
LOWDISK=y

# Specify the method to use to retrieve the track information,
# the alternative is to specify 'cddb':
CDDBMETHOD=cddb

# Make a local cache of cddb entries and then volunteer to use 
# these entries when and if they match the cd:
CDDBCOPYLOCAL="y"
CDDBLOCALDIR="$HOME/.cddb"
CDDBLOCALRECURSIVE="y"
CDDBUSELOCAL="y"

# Specify the encoder to use for FLAC. In this case
# flac is the only choice.
FLACENCODERSYNTAX=flac
MP3ENCODERSYNTAX=lame
# Specify the path to the selected encoder. In most cases the encoder
# should be in your $PATH as I illustrate below, otherwise you will 
# need to specify the full path. For example: /usr/bin/flac
FLAC=flac
LAME=/usr/bin/lame
# Specify your required encoding options here. Multiple options can
# be selected as '--best --another-option' etc.
# Overall bitrate is about 880 kbs/s with level 8.
FLACOPTS='-s -e -V -8' 
LAMEOPTS='--preset extreme'

# Output type for FLAC.
OUTPUTTYPE="mp3"

# The cd ripping program to use. There are a few choices here: cdda2wav,
# dagrab, cddafs (Mac OS X only) and flac. New to abcde 2.7 is 'libcdio'.
CDROMREADERSYNTAX=cdparanoia            

# Give the location of the ripping program and pass any extra options,
# if using libcdio set 'CD_PARANOIA=cd-paranoia'.
CDPARANOIA=cdparanoia  
CDPARANOIAOPTS="--never-skip=40"

# Give the location of the CD identification program:       
CDDISCID=cd-discid            

# Give the base location here for the encoded music files.
OUTPUTDIR="/home/adures/Desktop/Music"               

# The default actions that abcde will take.
ACTIONS=cddb,playlist,getalbumart,read,encode,replaygain,tag,move,clean

# Decide here how you want the tracks labelled for a standard 'single-artist',
# multi-track encode and also for a multi-track, 'various-artist' encode:
OUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}/${TRACKNUM}.${TRACKFILE}'
VAOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various Artists/${ALBUMFILE}/${TRACKNUM}.${ARTISTFILE}-${TRACKFILE}'

# Decide here how you want the tracks labelled for a standard 'single-artist',
# single-track encode and also for a single-track 'various-artist' encode.
# (Create a single-track encode with 'abcde -1' from the commandline.)
ONETRACKOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}'
VAONETRACKOUTPUTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various Artists/${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}'

# Create playlists for single and various-artist encodes. I would suggest
# commenting these out for single-track encoding.
PLAYLISTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/${ARTISTFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}.m3u'
VAPLAYLISTFORMAT='${OUTPUT}/Various Artists/${ALBUMFILE}/${ALBUMFILE}.m3u'

# This function takes out dots preceding the album name, and removes a grab
# bag of illegal characters. It allows spaces, if you do not wish spaces add
# in -e 's/ /_/g' after the first sed command.
mungefilename ()
{
  echo "$@" | sed -e 's/^\.*//' | tr -d ":><|*/\"'?[:cntrl:]"
}

# What extra options?
MAXPROCS=2                              # Run a few encoders simultaneously
PADTRACKS=y                             # Makes tracks 01 02 not 1 2
EXTRAVERBOSE=2                          # Useful for debugging
COMMENT='abcde version 2.8.1'           # Place a comment...
EJECTCD=y                               # Please eject cd when finished :-)
```

Do you have any ideas what might be missing?

**Edit**: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

**Edit2**: I pasted logs two times instead of logs and abcde.conf now fixed.

Comment: Looks like your copy of abcde is missing mp3gain, which is not available in 18.04. You should have access to a configuration file here: `/home/arm/.abcde.conf`, can you post the contents of this file? It will then be easy enough to remove the offending lines...

Comment: That's what I meant to do, but pasted two times logs. Now it's edited.

Comment: I recognise the conf file as an edited one from an older version of my web site :). Under 'ACTIONS' remove 'replaygain,' and then all should be well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from your `.abcde.conf` file where you have specified the following:

```
ACTIONS=cddb,playlist,getalbumart,read,encode,replaygain,tag,move,clean
```

The offender is `replaygain,` which works well enough when you are encoding to flac as abcde uses `metaflac` to add the replaygain information. However when you are encoding to mp3 abcde calls for a replaygain application called `mp3gain` which is *no longer available* in Ubuntu 18.04.

The easiest fix is to simply *omit* the replaygain 'action' as follows:

```
ACTIONS=cddb,playlist,getalbumart,read,encode,tag,move,clean
```

And then all should be well...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. And for explanation.

Comment: @Adures And all the best with abcde (and ARM). I was a developer for abcde for a few years and it is good to see this great application still in use :)

Comment: Wha can i say, that project is a godsend for me. I have few hundred CDs to rip. Thanks again :)